# KeyError in Python, even though the key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have been scratching my head on this for a few days now and cannot seem to find a solution that works online for my problem. I am trying to access data on zendesk and go through the pagination. For some reason, I am getting a KeyError, even though I can see that the key does exist. Here is my code :

```
data_users2 = [[]]
while url_users:
    users_pagination = requests.get(url_users,auth=(user, pwd))

    data_user_page = json.loads(users_pagination.text)

    print (data_user_page.keys())

    for user in data_user_page['users']:
        data_users2.append(user)
    url = data_user_page['next_page']
```

Here is the output :

```
dict_keys(['users', 'next_page', 'previous_page', 'count'])
dict_keys(['error'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-fab95d95ddeb> in <module>
      6     data_user_page = json.loads(users_pagination.text)
      7     print (data_user_page.keys())
----> 8     for user in data_user_page["users"]:
      9         data_users2.append(user)
     10     url = data_user_page["next_page"]

KeyError: 'users'
```

As you can see, users does exist. same thing happens if I try to print the next_page, I get a KeyError for next_page.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks!

Comment: Note that you have two sets of keys printed out.  The `KeyError` didn't come from the first iteration, where a 'users' key actually exists, but from the second iteration which only contains an 'error' key.  (In other words, you did something wrong in determining the URL of the next page.)

Comment: You set `url` to the next page, but still use `url_users` in the next call to `requests.get`. You probably want to set `url = url_users` *before* entering the loop, then call `requests.get(url, ...)` on each iteration.

Comment: Can't believe i missed that, thanks! however, I still gives me the error with this....

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing in its second iteration of the loop, in that moment your keys in `data_user_page` are just "error" as you can see in the output you have pasted

```
dict_keys(['users', 'next_page', 'previous_page', 'count']) <----- FIRST ITERATION
dict_keys(['error']) <---- SECOND ITERATION, THEREFORE, YOUR KEY DOES NOT EXISTS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-fab95d95ddeb> in <module>
      6     data_user_page = json.loads(users_pagination.text)
      7     print (data_user_page.keys())
----> 8     for user in data_user_page["users"]:
      9         data_users2.append(user)
     10     url = data_user_page["next_page"]

KeyError: 'users'
```

EDIT: This could be due to the fact that you are saving the next url in a variable called `url` not `url_users`

Comment: Good call! Sorry I missed that. however, still get the message once I changed it!

Comment: is the output the same?